# GET request array from .htaccess to php file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a small problem.
Lets say we have the following lines in our .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When I get the URL in index.php, its basically:

> /something/somethingelse/yes

If i were to send an array as the 3th argument, how do I cast it to a PHP array:

> /api/firstArgument/second[]=1,second[]=,second[]=3/third

This will get routed to my function which might look like this:

```
public function api($first, array $second, $third) {}
```

I don't want to call it like

/api/?firstArgument=something&econd[]=1&second[]=2&second[]=3&third=something

So how do I extract the array from the URL if I know that the 2 argument should be an array?

Is there a built-in function for this or should i perhaps rewrite my routing? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php uses the ampersand to separate query paramteres.

Your also missing the "?" Which indicates you have parameters.

Try:

```
/something/somethingelse?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3/hello
```

With the new edit, you can use parse_str to convert your second argument to an array. This would be done in your router.

```
Parses str as if it were the query
string passed via a URL and sets 
variables in the current scope.
```

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: I've edited my post, this doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but you can add an array to a url like this:

```
$url = '/your/url/' . urlencode(serialize($array));
```

Then use *unserialize(urldecode())* if you'd like to use it as an array on that page.